# Troubleshooting Increasing Memory Usage in a Django Application Deployed on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

We've successfully built a web application employing React for the frontend and Django, coupled with the Django Rest Framework (DRF), for the backend. The backend component has been deployed on Amazon Web Services (AWS) via the EC2 and ECS services.

Currently, I'm observing a steady rise in memory usage for my container, as evidenced by the below graph.

[image: Container memory consumption]

The dips you see in the graph correspond to application deployments.

For managing our HTTP server, we're utilizing Gunicorn. The command used as an entry point is as follows:

`gunicorn booking_system.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=$workers --max-requests 100 --max-requests-jitter 25`

This command is intended to avert memory leaks by restarting the Gunicorn worker after a certain number of requests.

I would appreciate any advice you can offer. What diagnostic measures can I take to discern the reason behind the escalating memory usage?

Adding these options `--workers=$workers --max-requests 100 --max-requests-jitter 25` I would expect to maintain a regular memory consumption.

Comment: Does the memory usage increase correspond with any traffic increases or other resource usage? You can also try install glances (python library) in the running container. It can show you all the running processes and how much memory they are currently using